# Google Places Api Not working in Android app

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I was using android's autocompelete for fetching places but now I have just create new play console app for that I didn't get the option for Android Sdk for places rather there is option for places Api only but I am using same code as earlier Places Autocomplete and I am getting and error:

> Error getting place predictions:
>   Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED, resolution=null}

I am using following gradle :

```
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:16.0.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
```

and My Place Adapter code is :

```
public class PlaceArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PlaceArrayAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete> implements Filterable {
    private static final String TAG = "PlaceArrayAdapter";
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private AutocompleteFilter mPlaceFilter;
    private LatLngBounds mBounds;
    private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> mResultList;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param context  Context
     * @param resource Layout resource
     * @param bounds   Used to specify the search bounds
     * @param filter   Used to specify place types
     */
    public PlaceArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, LatLngBounds bounds,
                             AutocompleteFilter filter) {
        super(context, resource);
        mBounds = bounds;
        mPlaceFilter = filter;
    }

    public void setGoogleApiClient(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient) {
        if (googleApiClient == null || !googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient = null;
        } else {
            mGoogleApiClient = googleApiClient;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public PlaceAutocomplete getItem(int position) {
        return mResultList.get(position);
    }

    private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> getPredictions(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            Logger.showMessage("Executing autocomplete query for: " + constraint);
            PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results =
                    Places.GeoDataApi
                            .getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, constraint.toString(),
                                    mBounds, mPlaceFilter);
            // Wait for predictions, set the timeout.
            AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictions = results
                    .await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            final Status status = autocompletePredictions.getStatus();
            if (!status.isSuccess()) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error: " + status.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Logger.showMessage("Error getting place predictions: " + status
                        .toString());
                autocompletePredictions.release();
                return null;
            }

            Logger.showMessage("Query completed. Received " + autocompletePredictions.getCount()
                    + " predictions.");
            Iterator<AutocompletePrediction> iterator = autocompletePredictions.iterator();
            ArrayList resultList = new ArrayList<>(autocompletePredictions.getCount());
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                AutocompletePrediction prediction = iterator.next();
                resultList.add(new PlaceAutocomplete(prediction.getPlaceId(),
                        prediction.getFullText(null)));
            }
            // Buffer release
            autocompletePredictions.release();
            return resultList;
        }
        Logger.showMessage("Google API client is not connected.");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Query the autocomplete API for the entered constraint
                    mResultList = getPredictions(constraint);
                    if (mResultList != null) {
                        // Results
                        results.values = mResultList;
                        results.count = mResultList.size();
                    }
                }
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    // The API returned at least one result, update the data.
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    // The API did not return any results, invalidate the data set.
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }

    public class PlaceAutocomplete {

        public CharSequence placeId;
        public CharSequence description;

        PlaceAutocomplete(CharSequence placeId, CharSequence description) {
            this.placeId = placeId;
            this.description = description;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return description.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Activity code :

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
GoogleSignInOptions gso;
private PlaceArrayAdapter mPlaceArrayAdapter;


private void googlePlaceApi() {
        gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .enableAutoManage(this, MYPerference.GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .build();
        etLocation.setThreshold(1);
        etLocation.setOnItemClickListener(mAutocompleteClickListener);
        mPlaceArrayAdapter = new PlaceArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW, null);
        etLocation.setAdapter(mPlaceArrayAdapter);
    }

    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mAutocompleteClickListener
            = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final PlaceArrayAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = mPlaceArrayAdapter.getItem(position);
            Logger.showMessage(" place id : "+item.placeId);
            final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);
            PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                    .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
            placeResult.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);
        }
    };
    private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback
            = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
            if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                return;
            }
            Logger.showMessage(" error : "+places.getStatus().getStatusMessage());
            Logger.showMessage(" error : "+places.getStatus());

            // Selecting the first object buffer.
            final Place place = places.get(0);
            CharSequence attributions = places.getAttributions();
            address = String.valueOf(place.getAddress());
            latString = String.valueOf(place.getLatLng().latitude);
            lngString = String.valueOf(place.getLatLng().longitude);

            //getLatLongFromAddress(address);
        }
    };
```

**Note** : Places Api is Enabled and unable to find any option for Places sdk for android and App billing is enabled and is working in Ios.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check with API key and package name whether it is correct or not.

Comment: have you seen: https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration ?

Comment: @Nik thanks. Everything is correct

Comment: @Bryant thanks but Places SDK for Android service in your Google Cloud Platform project is not showing. Thats the issue. And Migrating code is not seen to being compatible.

Comment: @bryant in migration do you have idea how to get place id

Comment: @RamanSidhu I am not sure, but it seems there may have been some changes to the Google Cloud Platform and Places SDK configuration. So you may not see the option for "Places SDK for android."  So if you are having trouble setting up your api key, can you look again at https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/start or possibly, https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/signup to see how you might register your api key?  Do those links help?

Comment: @bryant thanks a lot I am able to do it, now Android/Ios sdk for Places has been removed and replaced with Place Api and so does code.